# android listening to notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an app in which I want to listen to notifications from an app on the phone. I'm pretty new to android development, so any guidance would be appreciated.

My thought is that I need to create my service that extends `AccessibilityService` and implement `onAccessibilityEvent`.

I'm not sure then how to connect my service to the app whose notifications I want to listen to...

Comment: Are you actually building something for accessibility?

Comment: I'm trying to add a vibration when the app raises a notification event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "connect my service to the app whose notifications I want to listen to" -- you will get *all* notifications from *all* apps, because the point behind `AccessibilityService` is to actually provide accessibility features. A blind user is not blind for one app, but for all apps.

That being said, you are welcome to examine the `AccessibilityEvent` to see where it came from.

Comment: This isn't really true. You can specify which packages you want to listen to and only listen to those packages. This is part of setting up an AccessibilityService.

Comment: @CamilleSévigny: I even looked for this back when I answered the question and didn't find anything. The docs are a little weak on this. I now see `packageNames` in `AccessibilityServiceInfo`. Can you set `packageNames` in the metadata? If so, is it `android:packageNames`? Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare: That's a good question, I am not sure. I just started developing an AccessibilityService (which is why I decided to post my comment). If I recall, the docs said something about the Meta-Data tag meant access to all packages and only if you used SetServiceInfo() could you specify the packages that you wanted to listen to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Answer (score 1):

this might be possible on API 18 (android 4.3 jelly bean) , depending on your needs :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#43-beautiful-apps

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/android-43-and-updated-developer-tools.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Service which extends FirebaseMessagingService,  onMessageReceived method listens the Notification. Firstly you need to register for firebase token.